# Java Redis Spring boot Jackson- java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to MyClass

Tags: spring-boot, redis, jackson, jedis

Full error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class io.sylon.platform.tasks.client.TaskTreeResponse (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';mypackage.TaskTreeResponse is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

My Spring boot configurations

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {

  @Bean
  JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    return new JedisConnectionFactory();
  }




  @Bean
  @Primary
  public RedisCacheConfiguration defaultCacheConfig(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
        .serializeKeysWith(
            RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer()))
        .serializeValuesWith(
            RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(
                new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper)));
  }
}
```

The method I am calling

```
      @Cacheable(value = "taskAndChildren", key = "#taskId")
  public TaskTreeResponse getTasks(String taskId, Integer depth) {
    log.info("Method entered");
    return tasksApi.getTasks(taskId, depth);
  }
```

I cannot add serializable to TaskTreeResponse as it is from a library

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-linkedhashmap-cannot-be-cast

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27577